# Java mapping JSON with POJO using jackson

Tags: java, json, annotations, jaxb

I want to create this JSON using jakson annotated POJOS. The issue I have when I create a new class without @JsonProperty annotation to represent the last {"id":"123ccc","role":"dddd"}, it by default take the class name and create something like "customer":{"id": "123ccc","role":"dddd"}.

The JSON Structure I indent to build

```
{
  "relatedParty": [
    {
      "contact": [
        {
          "mediumType": "xxx",
          "characteristic": {
            "city": "xxx",
            "country": "xxx"
          }
        },
        {
          "mediumType": "yyy",
          "characteristic": {
            "emailAddress": "yyy@yy.yyy"
          }
        }
      ],
      "role": "ccc",
      "fullName": "ccc"
    },
    {
      "id": "123ccc",
      "role": "dddd"
    }
  ]
}
```

The JSON I'm receiving from the below code.

```
 {
  "relatedParty": [
    {
      "contact": [
        {
          "mediumType": "xxx",
          "characteristic": {
            "city": "xxx",
            "country": "xxx"
          }
        },
        {
          "mediumType": "yyy",
          "characteristic": {
            "emailAddress": "yyy@yy.yyy"
          }
        }
      ],
      "role": "ccc",
      "fullName": "ccc"
    },
    "customer" : {
      "id": "123ccc",
      "role": "dddd"
    }
  ]
}
```

What would be a workaround to get the exact JSON format as the image. Current Implementation is below.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

import java.util.List;

public class RelatedParty {

    @JsonProperty(value = "contact")
    private List<Contact> contact;

    @JsonProperty(value = "role")
    private String role;

    @JsonProperty(value = "fullName")
    private String fullName;

    private Customer customer;

    public List<Contact> getContact() {
        return contact;
    }

    public void setContact(List<Contact> contact) {
        this.contact = contact;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    }

    public Customer getCustomer() {
        return customer;
    }

    public void setCustomer(Customer customer) {
        this.customer = customer;
    }
}

    public class Customer {

    @JsonProperty(value = "id")
    private String id;

    @JsonProperty(value = "role")
    private String role;

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getRole() {
        return role;
    }

    public void setRole(String role) {
        this.role = role;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create additional and different POJO classes to model your JSON correctly. Basically, JSON arrays will be handle in Java lists, and JSON objects will be handled in Java classes.

Starting from the inside (most nested level) of the JSON, and working our way out:

*NOTE: getters and setters not shown here*

**Characteristic.java**

```java
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Characteristic {

    @JsonProperty("city")
    private String city;
    @JsonProperty("country")
    private String country;
    @JsonProperty("emailAddress")
    private String emailAddress;
}
```

**Contact.java** (contains our characteristics):

```java
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class Contact {

    @JsonProperty("mediumType")
    private String mediumType;
    @JsonProperty("characteristic")
    private Characteristic characteristic;
}
```

The above two classes handle the innermost objects. If we remove them from your target JSON, that leaves the following:

```
{
    "relatedParty": [{
        "contact": [...],
        "role": "ccc",
        "fullName": "ccc"
    }, {
        "role": "dddd",
        "id": "123ccc"
    }]
}
```

Note that the `contact` field is a JSON array, not an object - so we do not create a Java `Contact` class (which would be for a JSON object).

To handle the above I create two more classes:

**RelatedPartyInner.java** (contains a list of contacts)

```java
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class RelatedParty_ {

    @JsonProperty("contact")
    private List<Contact> contact = null;
    @JsonProperty("role")
    private String role;
    @JsonProperty("fullName")
    private String fullName;
    @JsonProperty("id")
    private String id;
}
```

**RelatedParty.java** (wraps everything in an outer object):

```java
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
public class RelatedParty {

    @JsonProperty("relatedParty")
    private List<RelatedPartyInner> relatedParty = null;
}
```

To test this I create the following data:

```java
Characteristic chr1 = new Characteristic();
chr1.setCity("xxx");
chr1.setCountry("xxx");
Characteristic chr2 = new Characteristic();
chr2.setEmailAddress("yyy@yy.yyy");

Contact con1 = new Contact();
con1.setMediumType("xxx");
con1.setCharacteristic(chr1);
Contact con2 = new Contact();
con2.setMediumType("yyy");
con2.setCharacteristic(chr2);
List<Contact> cons = new ArrayList<>();
cons.add(con1);
cons.add(con2);

RelatedPartyInner rpi1 = new RelatedPartyInner();
rpi1.setContact(cons);
rpi1.setRole("ccc");
rpi1.setFullName("ccc");
RelatedPartyInner rpi2 = new RelatedPartyInner();
rpi2.setId("123ccc");
rpi2.setRole("dddd");
List<RelatedPartyInner> rpis = new ArrayList<>();
rpis.add(rpi1);
rpis.add(rpi2);

RelatedParty rp = new RelatedParty();
rp.setRelatedParty(rpis);
```

Finally, we can generate the JSON:

```java
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.writeValue(new File("rp.json"), rp);
```

The resulting file contains the following:

```
{
    "relatedParty": [{
        "contact": [{
            "mediumType": "xxx",
            "characteristic": {
                "city": "xxx",
                "country": "xxx"
            }
        }, {
            "mediumType": "yyy",
            "characteristic": {
                "emailAddress": "yyy@yy.yyy"
            }
        }],
        "role": "ccc",
        "fullName": "ccc"
    }, {
        "role": "dddd",
        "id": "123ccc"
    }]
}
```